# Is there anyway to access the GET variable in angularJS

Tags: angularjs, get

How can I access the GET variable of the current PHP script that the AngularJS script is bootstrapped to?

I read that the $window service will give window-bounded variables to the controller but I don't know how to access these. Is the GET variable even in this?

Comment: PHP is server side.  angularjs is client side.  Can't get there from here.  Whay are you trying to accomplish?

Comment: I have a page that loads a user's profile and normally is through a get variable in the url like:
server/profile.php?user_id=6
Was wondering if there was a way to parse it through AngularJS instead of passing it through ng-init or something

Comment: Have you looked at all at $http?  You will end up doing something like $http.get('server/profile.php?user_id=6');  Your php program will need to return json and not html.  Plenty of examples out there.

Comment: Right, but when I click a user's profile link, I can't send an http get request. The link takes me to the profile and the profile is dynamically generated by the user id of the profile which is passed through the url. Sending an http get request would mean changing the actual DOM to become the user profile wouldn't it? (after sending a request for user data to some PHP file)

Comment: Step back and work your way through this: https://docs.angularjs.org/tutorial You need to understand client-server interactions and the whole ajax thing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Without including ngRoute in your project you can use the $location service.

Inject the $location service into your controller (I'm assuming you know what this means as you apparently did it with the $window service)

You can then access the get variables with

```
 $location.search().user_id;
```

Hope this helps, Good luck!